# Hide html element when specific resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `twitter bootstrap 3.0`. When resolution of the screen gets changed to smaller the menu changed to mobile view. I have a `div` contained slider with images, so I want to hide that `div` when my menu changed to mobile view (when screen resolution small).

I tried to apply `css` classes on my div `visible-desktop visible-tablet` but it is not working.

Is there other way I can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### 2021 update / Bootstrap 5.1

See [Display property - Hiding elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

To hide an element on extra-small (portrait mobile) screen widths, use

```html
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">
```

That is hidden by default (`.d-none`) but visible on small or larger devices.

---

##### Original 2013 answer

If you're using Bootstrap v3, they changed the responsive utility class names. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

You probably want `.hidden-xs`

This was also documented in [Migrating from 2.x to 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration)

Answer (score 8):

Consider using media queries.  Something like

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .mydiv {display:none}
}
```

Comment: FYI Bootstrap uses *<768px* to detect small screens

Comment: FYI, no it doesn't but we know what you mean.

Comment: It did in 2013 when I wrote that comment ~ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes. The current version (5.1) uses 576px as the [extra-small device breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints)

Answer (score 4):

You just have to apply the Bootstrap classes as seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).   You can test them there also, if you resize your browser screen you can check wich ones are active.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">This is the div that will hide on mobile</div>
```

Should only be seen in any screen bellow 768px (mobiles)

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the class of that div `.hidden-xs`.. It's more simple. You are only telling that this div is visible on desktop and tablets, and not telling that it isn't visible in small devices.